# Apply log2 transformation only to numeric columns of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to run a `log2` transformation on my data set but I keep getting an error that says "non-numeric variable(s) in data frame". My data has `row.names = 1` and `header = TRUE` and is of class `data.frame()`

I tried adding `lappy(na.strings)` but this does not fix the problem

```
Shared_DEGs <- cbind(UT.Degs_heatmap[2:11], MT.Degs_heatmap[2:11], HT.Degs_heatmap[2:11])
Shared_DEGs1 <- `row.names<-`(Shared_DEGs, (UT.Degs_heatmap[,1]))
MyData.INF.log2 <- log2(Shared_DEGs1)
```

The data should be log2 transformed as an output

Answer (score 6):

I always recommend using 'tidyverse' to process data frame. Install it with `install.packages('tidyverse')`

```
library(tidyverse)
log2_transformed <- mutate_if(your_data, is.numeric, log2)
```

Comment: Similarly, especially in answers, I always recommend listing only the packages needed for the answer. Not everybody has the `tidyverse` meta-package available (due to policy or personal preference), so it would be immensely useful to list only required packages (`dplyr` in this case). If somebody is familiar with `tidyverse` then they can choose to load the whole thing themselves; if not, don't make them install the gig-or-so of other things. (I am not arguing the overall usefulness of the tidy packages, many of which I use daily.)

Comment: I suggest you are confounding soap-boxing the benefits of using tidy-packages with loading a behemoth meta-package. If somebody doesn't know the `tidyverse` and really just needs a quick hack, your answer is requiring a **significant** download and package installation just to get this to work. Since there is no indication in the question that any of the packages are already available, this might be unnecessary, and is almost certainly unexpected. If you want to soap-box `tidyverse`, that's fine, but please be courteous and at least *say* what packages are strictly required.

Comment: I believe you feel annoyed, my apologies. It seems extreme to label my *"please be **specific**'* as something petty or even contemptible (mongering). I am not in the "anti-tidyverse" camp and use many of the tools myself. My goal has been to help foster a concise community of answers, but you feel that I'm being rude with my suggestion for clarity and specificity. Again, my apologies, this isn't a battle.

Comment: @KeqiangLi I think you're misunderstanding--r2evans likes your method, but thinks you should replace `library(tidyverse)` with `library(dplyr)` (and I agree). The `mutate_if` method remains unchanged. The amount of code remains the same. It's still a one-liner. All of `tidyverse` **is** a significant download - do `install.packages("tidyverse")` on a new installation of R and see how long it takes! We just think you should provide new users with a way to step into tidy tools a little bit at a time---installing just `dplyr` here, as appropriate---instead of recommending then jump in completely.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way using `base R`'s `rapply`, kindly using the data provided by @r2evans.

```
rapply(mydf, f = log2, classes = c("numeric", "integer"), how = "replace")
#       num      int chr  lgl
#1 1.651496 2.321928   A TRUE
```

Comment: Holy c\*\*p, I've been using most `*apply` functions all these years and never used `rapply(..., classes=c(...))`. I always thought ... it doesn't matter. And even better, it works equally well without workarounds on `data.table` and `tibble`. (And it's almost entirely `.Internal`! 3x improvement on this 1-row frame.) This answer rocks, @markus: elegant, simple, faster.

Comment: (Okay, the speed improvement reduces well below 3x when the frame is much larger ... but it's still faster.)

Comment: @r2evans `rapply` is indeed very handy in cases like this. Didn't know it was also faster, but good to know. Best

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to run `log2` (or other numeric computations) on a `data.frame` as a whole, instead you need to do it *per column*. Since we don't have your data, I'll generate something to fully demonstrate:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(num = pi, int = 5L, chr = "A", lgl = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydf
#        num int chr  lgl
# 1 3.141593   5   A TRUE
```

```r
isnum <- sapply(mydf, is.numeric)
isnum
#   num   int   chr   lgl 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
mydf[,isnum] <- lapply(mydf[,isnum], log2)
mydf
#        num      int chr  lgl
# 1 1.651496 2.321928   A TRUE
```

What I'm doing here:

- `isnum` is the subset of columns that are `numeric` (integer or float). This logical indexing can be extended to include things like *"nothing negative"* or *"no `NA`s"*, completely up to you.
- `mydf[,isnum]` subsets the data to just those columns
- `lapply(mydf[,isnum], log2)` runs the function `log2` against each column of the sub-frame, each column individually; what is passed to `log2` is a vector of numbers, not a `data.frame` as in your attempt
- `mydf[,isnum] <- lapply(...)`: normally, if we do `mydf <- lapply(...)`, we will be storing a `list`, which overwrites your previously instance (losing non-number columns) and no longer a frame, so using the underlying R function `[<-` (assigns to a subset), we replace the components of the frame (a) preserving other columns, and (b) without losing the "class" of the parent frame.